# window.location.origin not working on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.location

I have a javascript code where I update a (full-)URL string to get the relative path only:

```
const url = 'http://www.example.com/map/123'.replace(window.location.origin, "");
console.log(url);
```

This code, when running on *http://www.example.com*, would log `/map/123`.

It works fine on my computer, but I noticed that on my Ipad and on my Android phone, the origin is not stripped.

Is `window.location.origin` not compatible with all browsers ?  And in that case, how should I handle this ?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at [the browser support table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin#browser_compatibility), this should not be an issue. Are you sure that `window.location.origin` this is the source of the problem, not a-la the actual URL being different or something similar?

Comment: Hard to say since there is no console.  But that works on my computer; so it seems there is an issue on mobile browsers.

Comment: Both iOS and Android support remote debugging so you can access the console if need be, although it does mean putting in the initial setup time. Alternatively you can also write the debugging output onto the page for a quick and dirty workaround.